# FindBugsで潜在的なNullPointerExceptionを検出できなかった

Tags: java, eclipse

以下のJavaのソースコードでFindBugsを実行すると、
カテゴリー CORRECTNESS - タイプ NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH
の警告が検出できると思っていましたが、実際には検出できませんでした。

[EmpService.java]

```
private void hoge(){
    // ~略~
    String emp_code = EmpUtil.getEmp(foo).getEmpCode(); // この行に警告を出して欲しかった。
    // ~略~
}
```

[EmpUtil.java]

※回答ありがとうございます。
　最初に、少し端折ってサンプルソースを書いてしまったので、もう少しありのままのコードを書きます。

```
public static Emp getEmp(String foo) {
    SelectedData lineCodeData = getLineCode(foo);
    if (lineCodeData == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String lineCode = lineCodeData.getData();
    Emp emp = getLineRecord(lineCode);
    if (emp == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Emp retEmp = new Emp();
    retEmp.setLine_cd(lineCode);
    retEmp.setLine_nm(emp.getLine_nm());
    return retEmp;
}
```

[環境]
実行環境：Eclipse(ver:4.4.2)のFindBugsフィーチャー(ver:3.0.1.20150306)
FindBugsの設定：報告する最小ランク=20、レポートする最低の信頼度=Low
JDK：1.7

この場合は検出されないものでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindBugsでは、単独のJava（クラス）ファイル内部のみを検索対象としています。
複数Java（クラス）ファイルをまたがってチェックを行いたい場合は、別のツールを利用する必要があります。

有償ツールでいば、

- jtest

  - フロー解析と呼ばれている部分がそれに相当します。
- coverity

などが有名です。

OSSツールでは、

- infer（facebook社製）

などがあります。

Comment: なるほど！すべて辻褄があいました。ありがとうございます。
Coverityは前職で利用していてとても便利でした。
が、社内で個人的に活動をしているので、OSSがありがたいです。プラスアルファの情報まで本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`findByName`メソッド内のコードがどのようになっているのかが判断できないので正確な回答はできませんが、FindBugsは静的解析ツールですので、実行しないとnullになるかどうかわからないコードはFindBugsの能力の範囲外であり、検出はできません。

例えば、`findByName`メソッド内のコードが下記のような場合は、
`findByName`メソッドがnullを返す可能性があるので検出される可能性があります。

```
if (foo.eqauals("foo")) {
    return new Emp();
}
else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
後だしですみませんが、getEmpの実態を書き直しました。
このようなgetEmpなら検知してくれそうですよね？

Comment: 検出していると思っていたのですが、IntelliJ IDEAの解析ツールの方が検出していたみたいです、すみません。このケースだとNP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATHは検出されないみたいですね。getEmpメソッドにjavax.annotation.CheckForNullアノテーションを付けておくと、検出希望行でNP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUEが検出されます。

Comment: 解説ありがとうございます！
なるほど、、検出されないのですね。自分ももう少し実験してみます。
最後に再度ありがとうございました。